# How can i gather the following metrics from VMware vCenter vSphere REST api?

Tags: api, rest, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

Could I gather the following metrics from VMware vCenter vSphere REST api?

- Datastore Read/Write IOPS
- Network Bandwith
- Cluster Memory Usage
- Cluster CPU
  Usage

Or is this data only accessible through the Powershell CLI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's only a limited subset of metrics available via the REST API and almost all of them are only for the vCenter Appliance itself.

The stats are available from the vSphere Web Services API, particularly the [PerformanceManager](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.PerformanceManager.html) service.

You can also access that through numerous programing languages ([vSphere Management SDK](https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/7.0/vsphere-management), pyvmomi, rbvmomi, govmomi, etc.), as well as PowerShell/PowerCLI.